# Trying to copy and paste a section of a column, with If statement, Runtime Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the first 17 columns of a table, for rows that fulfil certain criteria, this previously worked when copying the full row across, but the code no longer works, giving up Runtime Error 1004, saying "Method 'Range of Object' Worksheet failed"

The code is:

```
    Sub CopyRowsAcross()

 'Name Worksheets
  Dim e As Integer
  Dim wsd2 As Worksheet: Set wsd2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataSheet2")
  Dim wsBS As Worksheet: Set wsBS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Budget Summary")


'Set variables
For e = 3 To 1776
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = wsBS.UsedRange.Row - 1 + wsBS.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'Set Criteria for copying lines across
If ((IsEmpty(wsd2.Cells(e, 1).Value) = False And IsEmpty(wsd2.Cells(e, 4).Value)) = True) Or (IsEmpty(wsd2.Cells(e, 1).Value) = False And IsEmpty(wsd2.Cells(e, 4).Value) = False) Or (IsEmpty(wsd2.Cells(e, 1).Value) = True And IsEmpty(wsd2.Cells(e + 1, 5).Value) = False And IsEmpty(wsd2.Cells(e, 4).Value) = False) Then

'Particulars of copying
wsd2.Range(Cells(e, 1), Cells(e, 17)).Copy
*wsBS.Range(Cells(LastRow + 1, 1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues*
End If


Next e

End Sub
```

The starred row has been highlighted as the issue.

I'm hoping someone can tell me why it isn't working and how to fix it?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If not specified, `Cells` refers to the cells of the current active sheet, so always specify the worksheet or Range. On the other side, cells(r,c) returns a Range, so to Paste-Line can be simplified:

```
wsd2.Range(wsd2.Cells(e, 1), wsd2.Cells(e, 17)).Copy
wsBS.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AutoFilter functionality instead of iterating. Then copy the filtered range into the sheet required. 
So in your case it would look something like this:

```
With wsd2
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        'Based on your example, you need 17 columns (hence Q)
        .Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter
        'Set the criteria here - you can set multiple criterias if required
        .Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter Field:=<enter column number>, Criteria1:="<enter criteria for column>"
        .Range("A1:Q1").Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
End With

'Here I'm showing how to copy into a new sheet. 
Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index))
WSNew.Name = "Budget Summary"
'If sheet exists you can directly start from here and replace WSNew with wsBS 
 With WSNew.Range("A1")
    ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
    ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .Select
End With
```